# Foundation.utils.debounce event when triggered

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

What i need is a way to display a messsage in the page  from this code stating that they can only submit a comment every 30 seconds but i see no way whatsoever to aceive this is there a hidden callback or event i can hook onto?

```
        $body.on('keypress', '.commentForm textarea', Foundation.utils.debounce(function (event) {
        var $wrapper = $(this).parentsUntil('.confession_comments_element').parent();
        var $self = $(this);
        var $commentWrapper = $self.parent().parent().parent();

        if (event.which === 13) {
            if ($commentWrapper.find('.confession_comment_wrapper').length) {
                $self.parent().parent().ajaxSubmit({
                    'success': function (data) {
                        $commentWrapper.find('.confession_comment_wrapper').append(data);
                        $self.val('');
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
            $self.parent().parent().ajaxSubmit({
                'success': function (data) {
                    $commentWrapper.append(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    }, 30000, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can disable the POST button after a success submit and start a timer for 30 seconds that just enables it again. Something like:

```
     $self.parent().parent().ajaxSubmit({
         'success': function (data) {
             $commentWrapper.append(data);

             $('#your_post_button').addClass('disabled');
             setTimeout(function () {
                 $('#your_post_button').removeClass('disabled');
             }, 30000);

         }
     });
```

Comment: Actually you just reminded me that my method wouldn't work anyway, mine would only work if the user stayed on the page the entire 30 minutes. i need to be handling this server side.